# javascript addEventListener for click event calls the functions multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I have added an event Listener on click event for Html canvas element.
The function statements gets executed multiple time. first time the statements execute once, when i call the main fnction again, the click causes same function to execute twice and then thrice and so on

Here is the listener

```
 function initializeNewGame() {

        // Set block 
        cur = new Date();
        countDownDate = new Date(cur.getTime() + 5*60010).getTime();
        moves = 0;
        BLOCK_WIDTH = Math.round(BLOCK_IMG_WIDTH / TOTAL_COLUMNS);
        BLOCK_HEIGHT = Math.round(BLOCK_IMG_HEIGHT / TOTAL_ROWS);

        document.getElementById("canJigsaw").addEventListener("click", myFunction);

        function myFunction() {
            moves = moves + 1;  

            } 

        SetImageBlock();

        DrawGame();
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling this block of code several times - it adds a *new* event handler every time. Make sure you only call the `addEventListener` bit once and once only

Comment: @Jamiec : it worked . i added a boolean to make sure the function if not called more than once. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `initializeNewGame` is only called once. Each time it is called, it will add another click handler. This means that `myFunction` could be called multiple times for each click.\

Try adding a console log in the `initializeNewGame` to help detect if its called more than once.